# Change table row grouping on interactive sort SSRS Local Report Webforms

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, report-viewer2010

Does Local mode processing SSRS in Webforms support this king of feature?

I want the columns of the table implement interactive sort, so the user will be able to sort the detail rows easily. However, I have different groupings initially in the table. I wanted it to be removed as soon as the user clicks on the interactive sort button.

For example:

**Originally**

```
 | Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3
-Group1
 | A-Data   |  Data     |  Data 
 | C-Data   |  Data     |  Data
-Group2
 | B-Data   |  Data     |  Data
 | Z-Data   |  Data     |  Data
-Group3
 | D-Data   |  Data     |  Data
```

If I click the interactive sort of Column1, for example, the table will look like this:

```
 | Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3
 | A-Data   |  Data     |  Data 
 | B-Data   |  Data     |  Data
 | C-Data   |  Data     |  Data
 | D-Data   |  Data     |  Data
 | Z-Data   |  Data     |  Data
```